# Casting element of uint8_t to 32-bit variable on 8-bit platform or 32-bit platform

Tags: c

Lets consider two examples

***1: 8 bit MCU/MPU/Platform - Little endian***

```
uint8_t arr[5] = {0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5};//assume &arr[0] == 0x0
uint32_t *ui32 = (uint32_t*)&arr[1];
```

What is the value of `*ui32`? `0x2030405`?
Is it necessary `uint32_t` variable to be placed to an address multiple of 4 at this platform?

***1: 32 bit MCU/MPU/Platform - Little endian***

Pretty much the same example:

```
uint8_t arr[] = {0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8}; //again assume &arr[0] == 0x0
uint32_t *ui32 = (uint32_t*)&arr[1];
```

What is the value of `*ui32`?

I know that 32bit variables should reside in address multiple of 4.

Where I can find specification on this?

Comment: You're not using pointers here, so in both cases ui32 will contain the value `2` (`00000000000000000000000000000010`).

Comment: And if you *were* using pointers, the result would be undefined.

Comment: And this comment is unclear: `assume  &arr[0] == 0x0`

Comment: In both cases your definition and initialization is the same as `uint32_t ui32 = arr[1];`. The casting does nothing the compiler would not do anyway.

Comment: What you're trying to do is `ui32 = *(uint32_t *)arr` and while that will probably "work" for you, it will have various endianness, alignment, and undefinedness issues.

Comment: I noticed that I am not using pointers, so I changed the post

Comment: @Hairi Now, instead of a useable value, you have the address of the first item in the array.

Comment: Now you have Undefined Behavior on your hands (you're creating a potentially misaligned pointer). If you want to know more details, you'd have to look at your compiler documentation.

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Comment: @Hairi With your second edit, yes, `*ui32` will likely end up containing `0x05040302` on a little-endian machine.  But the code might also crash, because this is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Does it matter 8bit or 32 bits platform?

Comment: @Hairi I expect it will "work" just as well, and have just as many potential problems, on either kind of platform.

Comment: From a strict C standard view point, your code has undefined behavior. So there is no way to answer this question in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Language Lawyering

Your code contains undefined behavior and is non-portable.  For example, on some UNIX workstations I’ve programmed on, memory accesses must be aligned to the size of the operand, so most but not all of the time, attempting to dereference `(uint32_t*)&arr[1]` would crash the program with `SIGBUS`, a hardware error caused by the memory bus.  The compiler allows you to shoot yourself in the foot like that.  Casting a pointer like you did violates the strict aliasing rules of C, which causes **undefined behavior**.

You can get around this issue by writing `uint32_t x; memcpy( &x, &array[1], sizeof(x) )`, which the standard explicitly allows.  From this point on, I’ll be assuming you’re doing the equivalent of this.  If you were not using an offset into the array, you could also type=pun with fields of a union in C (although the rules are different in C++).

By the standard, the elements of an array must be stored contiguously, with no padding between them.  A `memcpy()` between some object `x` and an array of `unsigned char[sizeof(x)]` is legal, and the result is called its **object representation**.

Copying arbitrary bits to the object representation of any of the exact-width types in `<stdint.h>` with `memcpy()` is **unspecified behavior**, not **undefined behavior**.  It is a well-formed program, and you will get some valid `uint32_t` out of it, even though the language standard does not say what that has to be.  You aren’t giving the compiler permission to do whatever it wants, such as Kill All Humans.  This is only because the standard does not permit the exact-width integral types to have any bits other than value bits, and therefore, they cannot have **trap representations**, invalid bit patterns that cause undefined behavior if copied into a value of that type.  (The example in the standard is an implementation that stores a parity bit in every word.)

However, the other side of that guarantee is that the types `uint8_t` and `uint32_t` are not guaranteed to exist, and there have been a few architectures in the real world for which conforming versions of them could never exist.  (However, `unsigned char array[sizeof(uint_least32_t) + 1]` is guaranteed to work.)

### Tl;dr

A real-world little-endian implementation on which that code runs correctly would probably tell you that `*u32` is `0x05040302`.  Otherwise, we would call it something other than little-endian.  However, some compilers put the onus on the programmer to follow the strict-aliasing rules carefully.  They are known to produce optimized code that doesn’t do what you expect if you write through either pointer.

Comment: As long as we're language lawyering, I agree that copying arbitrary bits into the representation of a `uint32_t` and then reading out the value of that object as a `uint32_t` does not produce UB. As far as I can tell, however, the result is not implementation-defined either, but rather unspecified.  Yet that is not what the example code does.  Nothing is copied, and indeed no `uint32_t` object is declared at all.  Reading (part of) the value of `arr` via an lvalue of type `uint32_t` violates the strict aliasing rule (C2011 6.5/7) and therefore produces UB.

Answer (score 2):

> ***1: 8 bit MCU/MPU/Platform - Little endian***
>
> ```
> uint8_t arr[5] = {0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5};//assume &arr[0] == 0x0
> uint32_t *ui32 = (uint32_t*)&arr[1];
> ```
>
> What is the value of `*ui32`?

C explicitly declares the effect of reading the value of `*ui32` to be undefined in that case, on account of reading the value of an object (part of `arr`) via an lvalue of a different type.

> `0x2030405`?

It is by no means guaranteed, yet not so uncommon in practice, that the value obtained by reading `*ui32` would be that of interpreting the bit pattern comprising elements 1 - 4 of `arr` as that of a `uint32_t`, but what number that represents is unspecified.  It is left to implementations to determine how to map physical bytes to logical ones.

However, if by "little-endian" you mean that the C implementation's `uint32_t` is represented by a four-8-bit-byte sequence in least-significant to most-significant order, and if you suppose that dereferencing the pointer indeed does successfully interpret the pointed-to bit pattern as that of a `uint32_t`, then the resulting value would be the same as that represented by the integer constant `0x05040302u`.

> Is it necessary `uint32_t`
>   variable to be placed to an address multiple of 4 at this platform?

You have not specified a platform, nor even a particularly narrow *class* of platforms.  I would generally expect an 8-bit platform not to require 4-byte alignment for objects of type `uint32_t`, but C does not specify, and platforms and implementations may vary.

> ***1: 32 bit MCU/MPU/Platform - Little endian***
>
> Pretty much the same example:

Exactly the same answer, except that it is more likely -- but by no means certain -- that 4-byte alignment would be required for objects of type `uint32_t`.

> I know that 32bit variables should reside in address multiple of 4.

Not necessarily.  Some 32-bit platforms indeed do require it; some do not require it, but offer faster access for aligned objects; and some don't care at all.

> Where I can find specification on this?

Such details of your C implementation of interest as are available at all would be found in that implementation's documentation.  The underlying system's ABI and / or hardware documentation might serve as a secondary source.

Overall, however, the best recommendation is usually to avoid such questions altogether.  Avoiding unspecified, implentation-defined, and especially undefined behaviors would allow you to rely wholly on the C standard to predict the behavior of your program.

Answer (score 0):

> **8 bit MCU/MPU/Platform - Little endian**

The answer will assume the platform, somehow, support longer integers even if the CPU might not, and that they are little-endian.

Note that, if a uC is truly 8-bit and has no notion of longer integers, then it does not make much sense to talk about its (byte) endianness. We could say, for instance, that it is both little-endian and big-endian (or that it is not any of those).

> ```
> //assume &arr[0] == 0x0
> ```

This may be hinting that this is coming from some exercise about misaligned accesses.

> What is the value of `*ui32`? `0x2030405`? Is it necessary `uint32_t` variable to be placed to an address multiple of 4 at this platform?

It depends on the platform and on the options of the compiler (e.g. if the compiler is assuming strict aliasing, then this is undefined behaviour to begin with).

However, since this is a 8-bit platform (and assuming you tell the compiler to do what you seem to want to do), a fair guess is that `uint32_t` has to be supported in software and that unaligned accesses are not a problem. Assuming the integer is kept in memory as little-endian (as explained above) by that software implementation, then yes, a good guess would be `0x05040302`.

> **32 bit MCU/MPU/Platform - Little endian**
>   What is the value of `*ui32`?

Again, in this case, it would depend on the platform/compiler. In some of them, there wouldn't be any value even, since the CPU would trap when you try to read such an address (since `&arr[0] == 0`, `ui32 == 1` which is unaligned to e.g. 4).

> I know that 32bit variables should reside in address multiple of 4.

Typically, but depends on the platform. Also, even if a platform supports unaligned accesses, it may be the case that it is slower than aligned accesses (so you want them aligned anyhow).

> Where I can find specification on this?

On top of the C specification, you would need to check your compiler's documentation and your architecture's manuals.

Comment: @4386427: Feel free to detail how so :-)

Comment: NMDV, but even if it does not inherit it from some underlying ABI, every conforming C implementation will have specific representations for its integer types wider than `char`.  We tend to refer to this as "endianness", though there are, in fact, many more options than just little- and big-endian.  It makes perfect sense to talk about this, including in the context of machines having an 8-bit native word size.

Comment: Endianness is about how data is stored in memory. LSB or MSB first. It has nothing to do with the width of the processor architecture. A 32 bit system still stores 64 bit integers with a specific endianness.

Comment: Quote: " ... then yes, a good guess would be 0x02030405" No, that a bad guess. If the access is at all valid, a more likely it's 0x05040302. After all it's a little endian system.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Yeah, that is why I said it would be a software implementation, rather than native support by the uC. Since the question says "8-bit MCU/MPU/Platform", I was assuming the OP is talking about the arch, not the compiler. But I see your point -- it is probably there (assuming this is an exercise) so that the answer to the "what the value is?" can be answered. Thanks!

Comment: @4386427: Regarding your 2nd comment: If everything in a uC is 8-bit (as I understood by "8 bit MCU/MPU/Platform"), it will typically not support 16-bit integers, which means there is no point talking about its endianness -- this is what I was trying to convey. Of course, the compiler may support longer integers (as John explained and as I was saying in another paragraph in the answer). Regarding your 3rd comment: The answer explicitly says it is taking "big-endian" as the guess; but I will change it, so that you are less grumpy ;-)

Comment: Removed DV... Grumpy... well, you may call me what you want but I would prefer a less patronicing word

Comment: @Acorn, every conforming C implementation supports integers at least 64 bits wide.  This is the size required for the minimum range of type `long long`.  Implementations conforming only to earlier standards that did not require `long long` will still provide integers at least 32 bits wide (required for the minimum range of type `long`).

Comment: "Endianness is about how data is stored in memory. LSB or MSB first. It has nothing to do with the width of the processor architecture" is an interesting comment - yet I do not agree with it.  If the processor's native working data width is P-bits (e.g. 8, 16, 32, 64) and addressing resolution is A-bits (e.g. overwhelmingly 8 but others exist), then anytime P > A, then endian issues come up in C.  It is because of P > A that the processor will have a machine defined endian.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: The C standard is not really relevant here (i.e. very small uCs). Even if a compiler chooses to support 16- or 32-bit integers (in software), they may be useless in practice (due to the speed and specially the program size hit). While in many cases, for such limited uCs, it is true you may want to be programming directly in assembler; it is still useful to have a C compiler around (even if it is not conforming -- it may not even come with a stdlib at all).

Comment: @Acorn, if the question is not about conforming C implementations, or at least about implementations that conform to an obsolete version of the C standard, then on what basis are we supposed to answer?  There is a reason that SO has no [unspecified-C-like-language] tag.

Comment: @4386427: No offense intended -- I felt you were a bit too emotive/annoyed on your initial comments; if you weren't, I withdraw the "grumpy" part :-)

Comment: @JohnBollinger: There are many non-conforming C compilers (specially a few years ago; also for C++). The fact that they are not conforming does not mean we cannot answer questions about them. I feel there is a strong trend in StackOverflow to always try to frame questions around strictly standard C; even when the question is clearly not referring to it or the intended reader is not knowledgeable enough. The reality is that there are many questions that can be discussed about non-standard C (or C++). For instance, I doubt this one (which looks like a u-arch exercise to me) is about C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Actually, I don't agree with the "[unspecified-C-like-language] tag" either. But I don't agree with the [c] tag being "strictly C99/C11, nothing else" either. I would prefer the [c] simply meaning "C, in any of its variants" (including old ANSI C; and including C-like questions like this one, which are not really C but it is good enough to understand what OP is asking). Whoever wants to really talk about standard C can tag it as "language-lawyer" and as a specific version if needed. Rationale: I think the majority of readers of SO do not come here to talk about the standard :-)

Comment: @Acorn, agreed: the fact that a compiler does not conform does not mean that we cannot answer questions about it.  But a question tagged [c] and *not* specifying any particular implementation or otherwise explaining what aspects of C we are asked about can only reasonably be interpreted as a question about conforming implementations, because *anything else is not C*.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: See my comment above (I was writing it and we crossed comments). As for "because *anything else is not C.*", I don't agree. See, if we are going to be strict and pedantic, there is no "C" either. Do we mean ANSI C, K&R C, ISO C? Therefore, let that tag be "c11" or "iso-c" or "std-c". Whoever decided that "c" means "ISO/IEC 9899:2011" was in the wrong, in my opinion. I, for sure, say "Linux is written in C". However, according to you, that sentence is wrong. (and not just because of the version; think about the extensions applied, too :-)

Comment: Yes, @Acorn, in a strict sense, the Linux kernel is written in a language very similar to, but not exactly C.  And when we get questions about the kernel here, that provides the context to establish what language we're actually talking about.  We need to know what language(s) we're discussing to hold the discussion at all.  Whether you like it or not, the prevailing view among high-rep members frequenting the [c] tag, including myself, seems to be that absent specification to the contrary, "C" means the language of that name defined by the current international standard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Just consider for a moment that the "kernel C" is less like ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (the "C" tag) than the C in this version. :-) As for "We need to know what language(s) we're discussing", that is not completely true. As a counterexample, see this question. There is no need to know it is C11 (actually, it isn't; and it is clear from the context -- and still we got several comments and an answer talking about type-punning etc.). As for the argument of authority, sorry, that is invalid (*specially* considering how reputation works and how skewed it is towards old and active users).

Comment: On the contrary, it is not at all clear from context that the question is not about C11.  And that absolutely matters, because it deeply impacts what answers are correct.  It is not so much about whether people can write answers, but about how anyone can *evaluate* them.  In any case, you are of course free to disagree with the prevailing view. Over time, you might even manage to shift it.  Until then, however, disregarding it is likely to get you into debates about what "C" means here.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Sorry, but the question makes no mention *at all* about C11, much less about language standards. The *only* place where a given standard is mentioned is in the description of the tag (which are misused almost all the time by beginners). Moreover, under ISO/IEC 9899:2011, the answers are undefined. So, should we ignore all the context and details of the question (note that many would be superfluous in this case), assume OP is talking about ISO/IEC 9899:2011 (even if the answers are undefined) and that a legalese answer is expected just because the "c" was used? (...)

Comment: (...) Or maybe we shall be reasonable, try to understand his/her knowledge level, acknowledge that the question seems to be about computer architecture (endianness, alignment requirements, etc.) and selected the "c" tag because his/her code was simply written in "C"? You might even manage to shift your view, over time, as well! :) As for getting into debates, that is fine with me -- really, I am trying to improve the site, help people and discuss technical questions. If that costs me "SO's reputation", so be it... :(